# Emberjs v4 Unable to copy object

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am upgrading my code to V4 but I have come across a problem when copying objects. I think I have apparently implemented the Em.Copyable interface, but Em.Copy is not available to me so I get an error in the console. What have I done wrong? I have setup a simple jsfiddle to show the problem I am getting. I'm sure I'm just missing something, but the documentation has completely changed and there are no examples that are in date any more.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7NhNM/)

Take this object:

```
App.Key = Em.Object.create(Em.Copyable, {
    first: 1,
    second: 2
});
```

And this event (in jsfiddle it is a button, but it could be anything):

```
doClick: function () {
    var k = Em.copy(App.Key);
}
```

The following error message is received and code execution is stopped:

```
Error: assertion failed: Cannot clone an Ember.Object that does not implement Ember.Copyable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ember Object.create() has changed recently, it no longer supports mixins. There are a few alternatives. The most common is to add mixins when extending ember object. For example:

```
App.Key = Em.Object.extend(Em.Copyable);
App.key = Em.Object.create({
  first: 1,
  second: 2
});
```

If you really want to use add mixins during create, you can use the new `createWithMixins` method:

```
App.key = Em.Object.createWithMixins(Em.Copyable, {
  first: 1,
  second: 2
});
```

Now that your object has the Mixin, you'll find that the example still fails with: `Object [object Object] has no method 'copy'`. This is because the Em.Copyable mixin does not actually provide an implementation - it's just a way of signaling to Ember that your object supports the `copy` operation. You still need to implement the `copy` method on your class.

Comment: If the Copyable mixin doesn't provide an implementation, then where has the copy function gone and why has it been changed? It seems like I'm dancing through hoops when I could just use jQuery.

Comment: For example, are you telling me that I have to do something like this just to copy an object: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NhNM/1/)? Why wouldn't I just do the `$.extend` trick straight away?

Comment: Hard to say where it went, I'm not sure what version you are upgrading from but don't remember there being a default implementation of `Object.copy()`. API docs make it pretty clear that your code is expected to provide the implementation: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Copyable.html#method_copy - what's right in your case depends on how your objects work. Maybe just create a new instance? Ember is still pre-release you should expect api changes, for sure jQuery is more stable as it's been out for years. If you stick with Ember read the new guides especially the object model section

Comment: Re jsfiddle, yes that is what i'm telling you but you are right, for sure you don't have to. The $.extend trick is fine too, it's easier and could be the way to go. Ember is not trying to force use of a particular implementation here. The reason you might consider using Copyable mixin and implementing `copy` on an object is so that it will work in context of other operations. For example, if your object is in an `Ember.map` and you make a deep copy of that map.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you very much! I was just making sure that there wasn't something I was missing. As a note, I am upgrading from pre2, so it's only a couple of releases behind, and there was a native copy function in that release. It seemed weird to me that the copy function just disappeared completely when it was already there, so that is what mainly confused me (plus other stackoverflow examples suggested that copying was possible!). It makes sense now why I couldn't find what I was looking for in the docs, as I was sure that object mixins were possible previously (hard to tell if deprecated).

Comment: Reason this seems so hard is maybe because of mismatch between how jq and ember work. in jq it would make sense to use copy in this click fx, but in Ember what you really want here might not be copy but instead create(). Forget the copy able mixin. If App.Key extends ember object, setting some default properties, then you can use App.Key.create() to make a new instance of App.Key from the click fx. Make sense?

Comment: Hmm yes you have made me have a lightbulb moment. The Em change has inadvertently caused a refactor for more understandable and 'correct' code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
App.Key = Ember.Map.create({
    first: 1,
    second: 2
});
```

to create the default model, which will have copy method.